# Defining a data type that doesn't want to be defined

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I have a data type Polynomial r for polynomials in Haskell and a Ring instance for it. (The `class Ring r where plus :: r -> r -> r ; times :: r -> r -> r ; negative :: r -> r ; zero :: r ; one :: r` -- it's just a simplified version of Num).

Now I could define a polynomial such as `gauss = x^2 + 1` or `eisenstein = x^2 + x + 1` and then work in "Polynomial Integer/(gauss)" for the Gaussian integers or "Polynomial Integer/(eisenstein)" for the Eisenstein integers. That's the problem, I wrote it in quotes because it's not a real data type, and I can't figure out how to define it.

I first tried to do something like `data Quotient p = Quot p p` and then for example we would have `plus (Quot a i) (Quot b i') | i == i' = Quot (plus a b) i` Of course this is pretty bad already but it's not even possible to define `one` and `zero`. So I changed it to `data Quotient p = Quot p (Maybe p)` and I think I have a working implementation using that but you never know for sure if `plus` will work (it needs at least one `Just`, and if there are two they must be the same).

Is there any type safe (I mean not using unsafe functions) way to program this in haskell? I am pretty stumped. Thanks!

Comment: I think what you would really want are [dependent types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) (which don't exist in Haskell); this would allow you to say something like `data Quotient (p :: *) (q :: Polynomial r) = Quot p`, where the data type is parametrized by a value.  There might be a way to emulate it in this case, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you looked at the Numeric Prelude, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.2 ?  They've done a lot of work addressing these sorts of problems.

Comment: @Antal, I think your `Quotient` would work if you used a newtype for each polynomial.  Sounds like a pain though.

Comment: Are you wanting Eisenstein and Gauss polynomials to have different representations at the same type? If so, you might want to look at Jeremy Gibbons's implementation of complex numbers in section 2 of Unfolding Abstract Datatypes http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/adt.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implicit configurations](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/prepose/prepose.pdf) paper (cabalized [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection)) uses quotients of *Z* as an example; it should be straightforward to adapt it to polynomial rings (unless I'm missing something).

Edit: Not saying implicit configurations *themselves* are straightforward, far from it ;) - just the modification.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you could augment your polynomial type with an index or tag? If I understand correctly, your normal module would be something like:

```
data Poly r = Poly r

class Ring r where
  plus :: r -> r -> r
  times :: r -> r -> r

instance Ring (Poly Integer) where
  plus (Poly x) (Poly y) = Poly (x + y)
  times (Poly x) (Poly y) = Poly (x * y)

gauss :: Poly Integer
gauss = Poly 1

eins :: Poly Integer
eins = Poly 2
```

And you want to be able to safely differential between the two "sub-types" of the rings. Perhaps you could tag them as so:

```
newtype PolyI i r = PolyI r

instance Show r => Show (PolyI i r) where
  show (PolyI p) = show p

instance Ring (PolyI i Integer) where
  plus (PolyI x) (PolyI y) = PolyI (x + y)
  times (PolyI x) (PolyI y) = PolyI (x * y)
```

Our instances of the Ring now require an extra type-argument `i`, which we can create by having simple no-constructor types.

```
data Gauss
data Eins
```

Then we just create the specific polynomials with the index as an argument:

```
gaussI :: PolyI Gauss Integer
gaussI = PolyI 11

einsI :: PolyI Eins Integer
einsI = PolyI 20
```

With the `Show` instance above, we get the following output:

```
*Poly> plus einsI einsI
40
```

and then

```
*Poly> plus einsI gaussI

Couldn't match expected type `Eins' with actual type `Gauss'
Expected type: PolyI Eins Integer
  Actual type: PolyI Gauss Integer
In the second argument of `plus', namely `gaussI'
```

Is that something like what you were looking for?

**Edit:** after a comment to the question about `newtype`, I think this may also an elegant solution if you use `NewtypeDeriving` to ease the burden of re-implementing the `Poly Integer` instance. I think in the end it would be similar, if slightly more elegant than this approach.

Comment: You can declare `PolyI` as `data PolyI i r = PolyI r deriving Show`, at the cost of having to specify type signatures (`PolyI 3 :: PolyI Gauss Integer`).

Comment: Ah, that is true. In this situation, one could even define a simple function to do this (`polyIGauss :: Integer -> PolyI Gauss Integer`, likewise for `Eins`) to avoid having to type the possibly long signatures many times.

Comment: There is no need to do that `undefined` business: just `newtype PolyI i r = PolyI r`, and `gaussI :: PolyI Gauss Integer; gaussI = PolyI 11`.  Then hide away the `PolyI` constructor.